# How to conditionally mount host-container volume in dev environment and ADD at build time?

Tags: docker

Suppose my I checkout my code from github onto `~/repos/shinycode` .

```
$> cd ~/repos/shinycode
$> ls
Dockerfile
www/index.html
$> cat Dockerfile
FROM nginx
ADD www /usr/share/nginx/html
```

For deployment, everything works fine: checkout from github and run `docker build`.

In dev environment, however, I want to run the container using the same `Dockerfile` but also live-edit files in the `www` directory, such as would have if I supplied a `-v www:/usr/share/nginx/html` option to `docker run`.

What is the best practice in this case? Should I have a separate `Dockerfile` for dev without the final `ADD` command? Am I going about this in the entirely wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same Dockerfile and mount over the image's /usr/share/nginx/html folder with any external volume. The mount of the volume takes precedence in the filesystem and you won't see anything from the image at that location.

Comment: Great! And is that common practice or is it frowned upon?

Comment: The only issue doing it is that the code and method of including the code inside the container may be different between dev and prod. But you're specifically looking for a way to make them different so this is the least different way to do it.